# Gradle Build Failing: Could not get unknown property 'RunTheProgram' for object of type org.gradle.api.plugins.internal.DefaultJavaApplication

Tags: java, gradle, build

I have a project where there are roughly 10 java files in the ./src/main/java directory and I'm trying to successfully build and run the project with a build.gradle file. However I'm having some trouble getting the main class, which we will call RunTheProgram, to run after the gradle build occurs. It seems like the corresponding java files aren't being compiled at all. I know that I'm very close to figuring this out but if anyone sees what is wrong it would be extremely helpful. I've been fiddling with the gradle documentation and having trouble with it. Here is the build.gradle file and the stacktrace of the error below it.

Build Gradle File:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

ext {
    javaMainClass = 'Runner'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest:1.3'
}

application {
    mainClassName = RunTheProgram
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/student/374/my-gradle-project/build.gradle' line: 20

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'my-gradle-project'.
> Could not get unknown property 'RunTheProgram' for object of type org.gradle.api.plugins.internal.DefaultJavaApplication.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'my-gradle-project'.
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:92)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$2.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:77)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:211)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:69)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.execute(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:66)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.execute(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:63)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:48)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:63)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:41)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:105)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:68)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:687)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:140)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:60)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:41)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuild.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:274)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.configureBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:182)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:141)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:77)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:74)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:154)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:96)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:74)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:79)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'RunTheProgram' for object of type org.gradle.api.plugins.internal.DefaultJavaApplication.
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.getMissingProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:86)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.ConfigureDelegate.getProperty(ConfigureDelegate.java:130)
        at build_eznf5v9gtqoc6bf39v6nuj3uy$_run_closure4.doCall(/home/student/374/my-gradle-project/build.gradle:20)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:71)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:155)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:106)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil$WrappedConfigureAction.execute(ConfigureUtil.java:167)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ExtensionsStorage$ExtensionHolder.configure(ExtensionsStorage.java:197)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ExtensionsStorage.configureExtension(ExtensionsStorage.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultConvention.configureExtension(DefaultConvention.java:412)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultConvention.access$500(DefaultConvention.java:45)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultConvention$ExtensionsDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(DefaultConvention.java:349)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.CompositeDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.java:30)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript$ScriptDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BasicScript.java:133)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.invokeMethod(AbstractDynamicObject.java:160)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.invokeMethod(BasicScript.java:82)
        at build_eznf5v9gtqoc6bf39v6nuj3uy.run(/home/student/374/my-gradle-project/build.gradle:19)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:90)
        ... 102 more
```

Answer (score 0):

`mainClassName` requires a string, as otherwise `RunTheProgram` is considered a project property:

```
mainClassName = 'RunTheProgram'
```

However, looking at example #2 of the [Application Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html#sec:application_usage) documentation, the correct way of configuring the main class is:

```
application {
    mainClass = 'RunTheProgram'
}
```

(no `mainClassName`)